# Does "not performing gusl" have any effect on one's fast?

Tags: hadith

If a couple have marital relations then fall asleep and wake up at sehar time, if they start fasting at sehar time without gusl is their fast considered invalid?

If their fast is considered valid and the couple still haven't made gusl till Zohr (Dhohr) is their fast still considered valid?

In this situation what should the couple do?

Please explain in detail.

Comment: AFAIK only the Ibadi sect considers the fast void if one didn't perform ghusl before fajr http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17755/what-theological-and-historical-factors-distinguish-ibadi-islam-from-either-shia

Answer (score 1):

> If a couple have marital relations then fall asleep and wake up at
> sehar time, if they start fasting at sehar time without gusl is their
> fast considered invalid?

No, the fast is perfectly valid. The evidence for that can be found in the following hadith:

> ...A'isha said, 'I bear witness that the Messenger of Allah, may Allah
> bless him and grant him peace, **used to get up in the morning junub
> from intercourse, not a dream, and would then fast for that day.**'"...
>
> USC-MSA web (English) reference: Book 18, Hadith 11

---

> If their fast is considered valid and the couple still haven't made
> gusl till Zohr (Dhohr) is their fast still considered valid?

Yes, it is still valid. The state of junub has no effect on the fast.

Answer (score 0):

- Waking up after Fajr without ghusl in Ramadan has no impact on your fasting, keep fasting as normal, as Um Salamah said: The Messenger of Allah, peace be upon him may wake up Junub of intercourse, and he did not break the fast and did not compensate. narrated by Muslim.
- the couple need to :

  - Do ghusl
  - Pray Subh (Fajr) (Kadaa)
  - Pray Duhr

Advise: It is  **Mustahab** for muslim husband and wife to do wudoo after intercourse if he wants to sleep without ghuls, and that is stated in the Sunnah.

Comment: Please consider supporting your claims by adding references!