# Is my fast valid if I do ghusl after eating sohor?

Tags: sawm, ramadan, ghusl, nocturnal-emission

Sometimes when I wake up for fasting, I notice I had ejaculated (not the result of masturbation, but a wet dream). Despite that fact, I eat and drink completely, then I do ghusl in order to pray al-fajr.
Given I ate while not pure, will this fast be accepted?

Comment: Unless you follow the Ibadi sect https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17755/what-theological-and-historical-factors-distinguish-ibadi-islam-from-either-shia, (only then) no!

Comment: @Medi1Saif  you mean yes? I.e his fast is valid

Comment: @Medi1Saif I do not understand what you meant. From what I understand from the article you pointed me to, it seems my fast is valid but I do not understand you answer "no".

Comment: @youssouf the "no" is in case you followed the Ibadi sect, else of course your fast is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Inshaallah your fast will still be valid. The hadath (impurities) including farts, urinating, janabah, etc. are not the requirement for <strike>doing</strike> starting the fast. Those are the requirement for other obligation such as the five prayer.

See: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/14225/delaying-ghusl-from-janaabah-in-ramadaan-until-the-sun-has-risen-does-not-invalidate-the-fast

Allahualam - only Allah knows best

Comment: There are two kinds for hadath one requiring ghusl and one only wudu'.

Comment: @Medi1Saif correct, but hadath is not the requirement to begin fasting. But indeed, if you have janabah later during fasting, then your fast is invalidated