# Is performing Adhan in a natural voice preferred over reciting it in a melodious voice?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, adhan, reciting

In the question below:

[How are Adhan and Iqama recited in the Ibadi madhhab?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/51753/how-are-adhan-and-iqama-recited-in-the-ibadi-madhhab)

One of the answers has the statement:

> "Note that the adhan and iqamah are most correct if they are performed
>   in natural voice, and for the adahn especially it should be quite
>   -with small pauses- and clear voice (which is also preferred by imam Malik), not in a melodical voice as is usually done in the middle east
>   for example."

As @[Crimson](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/28089/crimson) points out in the comment section, do we have any point of reference which may explain if one is preferred over the other.

Comment: I think rejecting melodical adhan could be based on the practice of the people in Medina and the accordingly application of a hadith.