# Question regarding taking major bath in the mid day in ramadan

Tags: ramadan, wudu, taharah, muslim-practices

Husband and wife after intimacy, they didn’t take shower, direct had have their suhoor and didn’t prayed fajr! And took bath in the mid day!
Would the fasting of thiers be counted as valid?

Comment: IMHO this is covered in [What theological and historical factors dsitsinguish ibadi Islam freom either shia and sunni?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17755/what-theological-and-historical-factors-distinguish-ibadi-islam-from-either-shia)